# Regex: why does this connection formula ([\s\S]*?) not work?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have this line in my html page.

```
   <h3 class="font-weight-normal" itemprop="name"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="color-black">I LOVE PRINCE</a></h3>
```

And I want to use regex in order to match **I LOVE PRINCE** that is located between `<h3 class="font-weight-normal" itemprop="name"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="color-black">` and `</a></h3>`

I usually use `([\s\S]*?)` in these cases, much better than `(.*?)` such as:

FIND: `<h3 class="font-weight-normal" itemprop="name"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="color-black">([\s\S]*?)</a></h3>`

but this time it doesn't work. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution. My mistake.

`([\s\S]*?)` is a good regex, much better then `(.*?)`. But in my example, I forgot to escape the `(0)` with `\(0\)`

So, the correct formula will be:

**FIND:** `<h3 class="font-weight-normal" itemprop="name"><a href="javascript:void\(0\)" class="color-black">([\s\S]*?)</a></h3>`

Also, instead of **([\s\S]*?)**  you can use  **([^"]+?)**  or even **([^"]*)**